# How to detach Elastic APM agent?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm, elastic-apm

I am trying out Elastic APM.

I used automatic setup with `apm-agent-attach-standalone.jar`.
(I also used `-javaagent` flag (manual setup), and it worked fine)

```
C:\Users\dsm\Documents>java -jar apm-agent-attach-1.9.0-standalone.jar --pid 16832 --args 'service_name=test;server_urls=http://localhost:8200'
--args is deprecated in favor of --config
2019-09-04 15:05:01.353  INFO Attaching the Elastic APM agent to 16832
2019-09-04 15:05:04.619  INFO Done
```

Data was successfully recieved from the agents, and I used APM UI to monitor.

How do I detach this agent from the process?

What do I do if I want to stop this agent?

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/detach-java-agent/186305

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/detach-java-agent-runtime/191870/2

Answer (score 1):

You can start your application with argument `active=false`.

`C:\Users\dsm\Documents>java -jar apm-agent-attach-1.9.0-standalone.jar --pid 16832 --args 'service_name=test;server_urls=http://localhost:8200;active=false'`

Comment: I tried your commands above with CMD and PowerShell. But the process is still running when I check with --list.

Comment: `java -jar apm-agent-attach-1.12.0-standalone.jar --pid 18144 --args 'service_name=test;server_urls=http://localhost:8200;active=false'`

Comment: `java -jar apm-agent-attach-1.12.0-standalone.jar --list`

Comment: I still get data from the agent, and I can see that from APM UI in Kibana. I don't think 'active=false' works. (Even though the documentation says it will)   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/config-core.html#config-active

Comment: Ok, can you then try to run agent with config flag.
E.g like this:
`java -jar apm-agent-attach-1.12.0-standalone.jar --pid 18144 --config service_name=test server_urls=http://localhost:8200 active=false`

Comment: What exactly you see in Kibana, only metrics data, or traces too?

Comment: I'm gonna have to look at that later. My app is  a very simple springboot app. According to my memory, I saw metrics data and also request and many other graphs, and one method (the app had one method). But I just want to see apm-agent gone when I do `--list` . When I manually kill the agent process (kill), I don't see any APM services in Kibana APM UI(of course), but when I do the commands above, I still see services in KIbana APM UI.  service = test ( which I create with above commands)

Comment: You can read [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-disable-apm-via-environment-variable/180558/3) more about how the agent is working.